# Adding more data to a PDF document in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Straight to the point. I really need your help on this one.
I have an `app` that is running on `Codeignitor`.
It already produces invoices which are linked to "projects, team members, and clients into `PDF` format.

I don't need the invoicing so I want to convert that setup into a "`Job Card`" generating tool.

I want to know that how do I pull data from `MySQL` DB to show on the `PDF`? The data must be unique to each project. So if I select a client and a project that's linked to that client, I want to be able to also pull additional data such as the Project Detail, date started/ended and so on.
What must I do?

Comment: CodeIgnitor or [CodeIgniter](https://codeigniter.com/)?

Comment: Sorry, Codeigniter

Comment: I have managed to create views of the files i need like this:{$this->load->view(projects/project_description.php', $data);} but what i get is the heading (title of the file but not the actual data for the respective project.